# Exporting excel chart as image

Tags: c#, excel, charts, export

I have an Excel file which has a charts, these charts represent data in columns, in my program I change these data in columns and chart changes also, after that I export these charts in .png files, but there I met an exception HRESULT: 0x80030020 (STG_E_SHAREVIOLATION)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using RTO.Models;
using Novacode;
using System.Drawing;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System.Reflection;
using CommonLib.SharedModels;

namespace RTO
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void ReportRTO(RtoCommonData cmnData, List<Antenna> antennas)
        {
            Novacode.Image imageh, imagev, image1, image2;
            Picture pictureh, picturev, picture1, picture2;
            Paragraph pimg;

            var exApp = new Excel.Application();
            exApp.ScreenUpdating = false;
            var exBook = exApp.Workbooks.Open(fileLeaf);
            var exSheet = exBook.Worksheets[1] as Excel.Worksheet;
            Excel.Range r1 = exSheet.get_Range("A1", "A360");
            Excel.Range r2 = exSheet.get_Range("B1", "B360");
            double[,] d1 = new double[360, 1];
            double[,] d2 = new double[360, 1];
            int w = 1;

            var application = new Excel.Application();
            application.ScreenUpdating = false;
            var workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(fileExcel);
            var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[1] as Excel.Worksheet;
            Excel.Range rng1 = worksheet.get_Range("A1", "A361");
            Excel.Range rng2 = worksheet.get_Range("B1", "B361");
            Excel.Range rng3 = worksheet.get_Range("C1", "C361");
            Excel.Range rng4 = worksheet.get_Range("D1", "D361");
            double[,] data1 = new double[361, 1];
            double[,] data2 = new double[361, 1];
            double[,] data3 = new double[361, 1];
            double[,] data4 = new double[361, 1];
            int flnmadd = 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < antennas.Count; i++)
            {
                //Save chart as image
                w = 1;
                foreach (Excel.Worksheet ws in exBook.Worksheets)
                {
                    Excel.ChartObjects chartObjects = (Excel.ChartObjects)(ws.ChartObjects(Type.Missing));
                    foreach (Excel.ChartObject co in chartObjects)
                    {
                        co.Select();
                        Excel.Chart chart = co.Chart;
                        chart.Export(exportPath + @"\leaf" + w + ".png", "PNG", false);
                        w++;
                    }
                }

                //Insert image to doc
                image1 = doc.AddImage(leafimg1);
                picture1 = image1.CreatePicture();
                picture1.Width = 310;
                picture1.Height = 310;
                image2 = doc.AddImage(leafimg2);
                picture2 = image2.CreatePicture();
                picture2.Width = 310;
                picture2.Height = 310;
                pimg = doc.InsertParagraph();
                pimg.AppendPicture(picture1);
                pimg.AppendPicture(picture2);

                for (int j = 0; j < boztrows; j++)
                {
                    data1[j, 0] = sumbozres[i].Rxhor[j];
                    data2[j, 0] = sumbozres[i].Rzhor[j];
                    data3[j, 0] = sumbozres[i].Rxver[j];
                    data4[j, 0] = sumbozres[i].Rzver[j];
                }
                data1[boztrows, 0] = data1[0, 0];
                data2[boztrows, 0] = data2[0, 0];
                data3[boztrows, 0] = data3[0, 0];
                data4[boztrows, 0] = data4[0, 0];
                rng1.Value = data1;
                rng2.Value = data2;
                rng3.Value = data3;
                rng4.Value = data4;

                //Save chart as image
                flnmadd = 1;
                foreach (Excel.Worksheet ws in workbook.Worksheets)
                {
                    Excel.ChartObjects chartObjects = (Excel.ChartObjects)(ws.ChartObjects(Type.Missing));
                    foreach (Excel.ChartObject co in chartObjects)
                    {
                        co.Select();
                        Excel.Chart chart = co.Chart;
                        chart.Export(exportPath + @"\charthv" + flnmadd + ".png", "PNG", false);
                        flnmadd++;
                    }
                }

                //Insert image to doc
                if (antennas[i].Type == "БС")
                {
                    imageh = doc.AddImage(charthimg);
                    pictureh = imageh.CreatePicture();
                    pictureh.Width = 624;
                    pictureh.Height = 357;
                    imagev = doc.AddImage(chartvimg);
                    picturev = imagev.CreatePicture();
                    picturev.Width = 624;
                    picturev.Height = 156;
                    pimg = doc.InsertParagraph();
                    pimg.AppendPicture(pictureh);
                    pimg = doc.InsertParagraph();
                    pimg.AppendPicture(picturev);
                }
                else if (antennas[i].Type == "РРС")
                {
                    imageh = doc.AddImage(rrsimg);
                    pictureh = imageh.CreatePicture();
                    pictureh.Width = 624;
                    pictureh.Height = 156;
                    pimg = doc.InsertParagraph();
                    pimg.AppendPicture(pictureh);
                }

                trsprev += trs;
                freqs = "";
                pows = "";
                koefgs = "";
                koefgrazs = "";
                poteri = "";
                poteriraz = "";
                freqAvg = 0;
            }

            exBook.Save();
            exBook.Close();
            exApp.Workbooks.Close();
            exApp.Quit();
            workbook.Save();
            workbook.Close();
            application.Workbooks.Close();
            application.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: exception appears here: chart.Export(exportPath + @"\leaf" + w + ".png", "PNG", false);

Comment: STG_E_SHAREVIOLATION: "Access denied because another caller has the file open and locked". A guess is that you are denied access because an old file with the same filename is open/in use. Have you deleted the old files before re-running?

Comment: @NLindbom You are right, problem was because I'm creating and saving same .png files with the same name in loop. Firstly, I tried to delete file after every iteration, but there was an error smth like "couldn't delete, because this file is opened". So, I solved problem by creating different .png files for every chart. But, is it a good way to do that or there is another which better?

Comment: I posted an answer that hopefully gives you some idea that works for you. I don't think theres any solid "the right way to go" for this, it's more a matter of choice on how to do it. But I strongly believe any solution should use a try/catch statement for the saving. What happens after that is up to you :)

Comment: Think about how saving works in a normal application, if it doesnt work you try again and pick a different filename, if you make this a windows forms application you could do that aswell, if it fails open a file dialog to pick a filename of your choosing. But I understand that you want it slightly more automated. Perhaps settle with picking a different output directory as per my last remark in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Could be that your program has two instances of the same file. Another thing can be save the file before you're trying to save the picture.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the question comments HRESULT: 0x80030020 (STG_E_SHAREVIOLATION) is "Access denied because another caller has the file open and locked" more information [here](http://codeswamp.tolon.co.uk/codeswamp_80030020.html). The file was simply still open/in use, and can be resolved by first deleting the old files.

There are some options, and it depends on how you intend to use the program. Adding a try/catch statement will keep the program from crashing. Besides that I don't see any particular best practice, it depends on usage. *In my opinion it is entierly reasonable for the program to exit if it fails to save.*

In the interest of offering a solution that you can adjust to your liking: first a method for saving charts that returns true if successful (not pretty but does the job):

```
using System.IO;

private static bool SaveExcelChartAsPNG(ChartObject co, 
    string path, string filename)
{
    try
    {
        string filenamePNG = Path.ChangeExtension(filename, "png");
        string fullFilenamePNG = Path.Combine(path, filenamePNG);

        co.Select();
        co.Chart.Export(fullFilenamePNG, "PNG", false);
    }
    catch
    {
        // Save was not successful
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This solution will exit on unsuccessful save:

```
            foreach (var co in chartObjects)
            {
               if (!SaveExcelChartAsPNG(exportPath, @"\leaf" + w + ".png"))
                   Application.Exit();
            }
```

A longer example that will retry saving 10 times by incrementing the 'w' parameter, then try a random filename. If that doesnt work the program will exit.

```
            //Save chart as image
            w = 1;
            foreach (var ws in exBook.Worksheets)
            {
                var chartObjects = (Excel.ChartObjects)(ws.ChartObjects(Type.Missing));
                foreach (var co in chartObjects)
                {
                    int retry = 0;
                    bool successfulSave = false;
                    while (!successfulSave && retry < 10) // retry by incerementing w parameter 10 times)
                    {
                       successfulSave = SaveExcelChartAsPNG(exportPath, @"\leaf" + w + ".png"))
                       retry++;
                       w++;
                    }

                    if (!successfulSave)
                    {
                        // Try again with random filename, otherwise exit
                        string filename = Path.GetRandomFileName();
                        if (!SaveExcelChartAsPNG(exportPath, filename))
                        {
                            // Save still not successful, exit
                            Application.Exit();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

And a remark regarding the above code: (First off it's flawed, because if you already generate 10 charts 11 times you will always first generate charts 0-99 then you will end up with 10 charts with completely random names. In which case you might just want to generate random names to begin with.)
**In most cases it is not good to catch all exceptions and return true/false. Future problems can arise when some other Exception is raised that is not related to filenames. Both the user and programmer will be left oblivious to what happened.** It is better to demand filenames that can be used, perhaps make 'w' or the output filenames an input parameter to the program to offer some flexibility.

One last option could be to instead create a new random output directory to guarantee that it is empty and output the prefered filenames there. Also by using [`Path.GetRandomFileName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getrandomfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) that has the benefit over [`Path.GetTempFileName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) of not creating the file.